# Is it possible to generate complete C/C++/Java code from a State machine in Magic Draw?

Tags: code-generation, state-machine, magic-draw

I want to generate code from my state machine in Magic Draw. Magic Draw supports code generation for classes but does not include an option for state machine. I tried using [SinelaboreRT](https://www.sinelabore.com/doku.php) software. However, it generates limited code. We need to manually add 'Main' function and other functions defined inside states. I wanted to know if it is possible to  generate an executable or a C/C++/Java code file with all the code mentioned inside states as well a 'Main' function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are three main options that I am aware of 1) make your own code generator, 2) buy a commercial code generator e.g. `LieberLieber` provides what appears to be a fairly sophisticated one, or 3) use one of the open source code generators such as `Papyrus-RT`.

The first option isn't actually that difficult depending on your target language and framework. For my work at MITRE, I have written a generator to take properly formed Magicdraw models and create deploy-able Spring microservices. I used the Spring state machine library to simplify the STM code generation.

Answer (score 1):

I personally found most convenient way to create state machine from models is UML or any other DSL is the combination of

[Eclipse Papyrus](https://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/) / [Eclipse XText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) / [Eclipse XTend](https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/)

there is also new kind in the block, if you don't want to work Eclipse based

[Langium](https://langium.org/)

but they are suffering at the moment little bit from being new but I will advice you check them every 6 months, they seem promising.

If you want to see how is it done, I have several blogs about it.

UML Based:

[Akka Finite State Machine Generation](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/code-generation-with-xtext-xtend-for-akka-finite-state-machine-fsm/) [Blog2](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/)
[Papyrus and Spring State Machine](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2015/12/14/ajax-spring-web-flow-and-spring-state-machine/)

DSL Based:

[XText and Spring State Machine](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2016/01/20/xtext-domain-specific-language-and-spring-state-machine/)